# Call a public function (NOT in the MAIN) from another Class like showTheThumbs

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Can I call a class public function from another class? What is the cleanest solution to do that?

for example:

```
Main -------------------------- Menu
                                  |---------- buttonClicks

     -------------------------- Thumbs
                                   |--------- showTheThumbs
```

a button which is instanced in Menu, run showTheThumbs method, in Thumbs.

Comment: So is Main your Document Class ? Menu a different Class and Thumbs a next Class ? Are they in the same packages ?

Comment: yes! Main is the document class, Menu and Thumbs different classes, but all in the same package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an event

When working with Flex, you accomplish these things by dispatching an event and listening to it from another class.

This way, your classes are loosely coupled and nothing will break when you'll change something.

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you want is a *Static Method* that relates to the Class `Thumbs` but not the instance of the class. This is a way they can be accessed *[Edited after seeing what Avi wrote, yes this does create coupling :( ]*. As long as there are all in the same package, this should work

In Menu

```
public function buttonClicks(event:MouseEvent):void {
    Thumbs.showTheThumbs();
}
```

In Thumbs

```
public static function showTheThumbs():voud{
     TheDoSomethingFunction();
}
```